# QComboBox connect

Tags: qt, qcombobox, slot

I need to call a function with currentIndex+1 when the currentIndex of a QComboBox changes. I'm struggling with the syntax this morning:

```
// call function readTables(int) when currentIndex changes.

connect(ui->deviceBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged()),
   SLOT( readTables( ui->deviceBox->currentIndex()+1) );
```

error: expected ')'
       SLOT( readTables(ui->deviceBox->currentIndex()+1) );

Adding a closing ) won't work...!

Comment: Write it as `connect(ui->deviceBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), SLOT(readTables(int));`. The `readTables(int)` slot will be called with the current index as an argument.

Comment: If you'll use Qt version 5+ and c++11, then you can write `connect(ui->deviceBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), [this]( int idx ) { readTables( idx + 1 ); } );`

Comment: I recommend you read the `Qt Signals and Slots` documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First**. If you can modify function `readTables` then you can just write:

```
connect(ui->deviceBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), SLOT(readTables(int));
```

and in `readTables`

```
void MyClass::readTables( int idx ) {
    idx++;
    // do another stuff
}
```

**Second**: If you can use Qt 5+ and c++11, just write:

```
connect(ui->deviceBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
    [this]( int idx ) { readTables( idx + 1 ); }
);
```

**Third**: If you can't modify `readTables` and can't use c++11, write your own slot (say `readTables_increment`) like this:

```
void MyClass::readTables_increment( idx ) {
    readTables( idx + 1 );
}
```

and connect signal to it:

```
connect(ui->deviceBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
    SLOT(readTables_increment(int))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`QComboBox::currentIndexChanged` expects either a [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) or a [int](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) as the single argument. You have 2 errors here:

- you are not connecting to any existing signal since you specify `currentIndexChanged()` which does not exist
- you are not passing a `SLOT` as the slot argument which requires the slot signature; rather, you are trying to pass an argument "on-the-fly" which is not something allowed.

@borisbn suggestion is pretty good if you are ok with using C++ lambdas.
Otherwise you'll have to declare a new slot with an `int` argument:

```
void ThisClass::slotCurrentIndexChanged(int currentIndex) {
    ui->deviceBox->readTables(ui->deviceBox->currentIndex() + 1);
}
```